# Why does GPG seem to parse the whole encrypted file when it can't find the decryption key?

Tags: gnupg

You can try this one for yourself...

1. Generate a new GPG keypair.
2. Create a large junk file. Maybe 5G or 10G in size.
3. Encrypt the file and use the new key as the recipient.
4. Delete the privkey which will render decryption impossible.
5. Try and decrypt the junk file.

I get a message from GPG immediately telling me `gpg: decryption failed: No secret key` but then it behaves like it is scanning the other gigabytes of my file until it gets to the end and drops me back into my shell.

So why does GPG carry on trying to parse the file when it knows immediately that there's no key to decrypt it?